# Hours in Amazon Free Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm using a Amazon Free Instance in EC2.

So, I have 750 hours/month to spend one year long.

My question is: If I run 2 instances at the same time I'll spend 2x the number of hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Every instance is billed per-hour.

**However**, if you run a Linux AMI and Windows AMI at the same time you get 750 free hours for each.